# Displaying image based on multiple selection value(s)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a multiple selection box that I would like to use the value's from to display images based on selecting these values, eg. if one value is selected then one image would be displayed, if two are selected two would be displayed etc. I would also like a limit on it of three images displayed at once, no matter how many selections.

```
<select multiple name="item" class="details" action="post" id="mySelect">
<option value="one">One</option>
<option value="two">Two</option>
<option value="three">Three</option>
<option value="four">Four</option>
</select>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

What I've tried so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!--  
function showimage() {  
var htmlStr=""; 
var option = document.getElementById("selectedValue"); 
for (i=0;i<option.options.length;i++) { 
if (option.options[i].selected) { 
htmlStr+='<img src="/products/"; 
htmlStr+=option.options[i].value; 
htmlStr+='" /><br />'; 
} 
} 
document.getElementById('mySelect').innerHTML = htmlStr; 
}  
//--> 
</script>
```

The images are located in /products/..

Comment: Where are the images? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You'll need JavaScript. Please try something and share your code when it doesn't work. We'll help you out!

Comment: @ThomasBormans I've added what I've tried above. It's a script I found online somewhere, which I've tried to edit to suit me. I'm not the best at javascript as I've only recently started learning it.

Comment: action attribute is for forms,not selects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your html to this:

```
<select multiple name="item" class="details" action="post" id="mySelect" onchange="showimage(this.value)">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

And your JavaScript to this:

```
function showimage(option) {
    var htmlStr="";
    if(option > 3) {
        option = 3;
    }
    for(i=0;i<option;i++) {
        htmlStr+='<img src="/products/' + i + '.jpg" /><br />';
    }
    document.getElementById('images').innerHTML = htmlStr;
}
```

All your images should be in the **products** folder with names: 1.jpg, 2.jpg, ...

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to put correct image paths.

```js
function imageFunc(imageid){
 
 var Imageplace=document.getElementById("myImage");
  Imageplace.src=imageid;
  }
```

```html
<select multiple name="item" class="details"  id="mySelect" onchange="imageFunc(this.value)";>
<option value="1.jpg">One</option>
<option value="2.jpg">Two</option>
<option value="3.jpg">Three</option>
<option value="4.jpg">Four</option>
</select>
<img id="myImage" src="1.jpg"/>
```